# Custom different sizes of labels in a stacked bar chart (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to customize different sizes for the labels inside a stacked barchart using ggplot2.

For example, a size 4 in the green bar, a size 3 in the light green, a size 2 in the yellow and so on. Below there is a link with an image of the plot. I cant figure out how to do it.

This is the code

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = as.factor(id), y=value, fill = cat, label = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha=0.5) +
  geom_text(size = 2.5, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.7)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#1E8E6B", "#6FBC84", "#FEEF51", "#EF6541", "#E81329"))
```

I want for example

[image]

Comment: Could you not simply do an `aes(size = cat)` combined with a `scale_size_manual()`?

Answer (score 0):

As @teunbrand mentioned, put your `size=` into `aes()` so that `ggplot2` uses that as an aesthetic mapped to `cat`, and then use `scale_size_manual()` to set the sizes just like you already have done with the `fill=`.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = as.factor(id), y=value, fill = cat, label = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha=0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(size = cat), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.7)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#1E8E6B", "#6FBC84", "#FEEF51", "#EF6541", "#E81329")) +
  scale_size_manual(values=c(4,3,2.5,2,1.5))
```

You can change the sizes however you wish or set values with a `seq()` function.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies! I could do it just as you told me :)